# Model cascading in the JSONMedel library not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cascading, jsonmodel

I am using JSONModel library for creating models from the API responses of my project. I am trying to access userDetails.user.firstName where userDetails is of type LoginModel and this is the .h file for it:

```
 #import <JSONModel/JSONModel.h>

 @interface UserModel : JSONModel
 @property (nonatomic) NSInteger userId;
 @property (nonatomic) NSString *firstName;
 @property (nonatomic) NSString *lastName;
 @property (nonatomic) NSString *email;
 @property (nonatomic) NSURL <Optional> *profilePictureUrl;
 @property (nonatomic) BOOL tosSigned;
 @property (nonatomic) BOOL emailVerified;
 @property (nonatomic) NSDate *createdAt;
 @property (nonatomic) NSArray *activePromos;
 @property (nonatomic) BOOL hasPaymentSource;
 @property (nonatomic) NSDictionary *emergencyContact;
 @property (nonatomic) NSString *referralCode;
 @property (nonatomic) float balance;

 @end

 @interface LoginModel : JSONModel

 @property (nonatomic) NSInteger expiresIn;
 @property (nonatomic) NSString *accessToken;
 @property (nonatomic) NSString *refreshToken;
 @property (nonatomic) UserModel *user;

 @end
```

But, every time I am trying to access the elements of the UserModel, its throwing the following error:

[__NSDictionaryI firstName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8fab61f430. Here is the API response sample that I am getting that I need to access through my model class:

```
{"expiresIn": 900000,
"accessToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiIxMDg2ODI3ODg2IiwiYWNjb3VudFR5cGUiOiJjdXN0b21lciIsImlhdCI6MTUzNjU4MzAyNiwiZXhwIjoxNTM2NTg2NjI2LCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2c0bmlvYjFlZ2wuZXhlY3V0ZS1hcGkudXMtZWFzdC0xLmFtYXpvbmF3cy5jb20vbGF0ZXN0IiwiaXNzIjoicG9waW4ubnljIiwic3ViIjoiMTA4NjgyNzg4NiJ9.qK_GYoPgRDnrrp3zrsWMZuPxJi1T3O-9lAPwbYdwtccJ63cTPBSTlWlbpuYMJXRRLEu371xfzBbImb-6I-8sxQ",
"refreshToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiIxMDg2ODI3ODg2IiwiYWNjb3VudFR5cGUiOiJjdXN0b21lciIsImlhdCI6MTUzNjU4MzAyNiwiZXhwIjoxNTY4MTQwNjI2LCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2c0bmlvYjFlZ2wuZXhlY3V0ZS1hcGkudXMtZWFzdC0xLmFtYXpvbmF3cy5jb20vbGF0ZXN0IiwiaXNzIjoicG9waW4ubnljIiwic3ViIjoiMTA4NjgyNzg4NiJ9.xIjuj87dVs5BMJOLKoh47Vx7RXVcSiPb6hGIzdbVWlrYa6gNh7s1wlQOy9U44PJ7hUCUPYHc8V7i4TVD7mtC2A",
"user": {
    "userId": "1086827886",
    "firstName": "JP",
    "lastName": "Kocher",
    "email": “********”,
    "profilePictureUrl": null,
    "tosSigned": false,
    "emailVerified": true,
    "createdAt": "2018-09-04T14:21:22.486Z",
    "activePromos": [],
    "hasPaymentSource": false,
    "emergencyContact": {},
    "balance": 0,
    "referralCode": "jpk6334"
}}
```

Please help.

Comment: How are you creating your objects? The error says you're getting a `NSDictionary` and it should be a `LoginModel` object. When getting your JSON string, you should be doing something like `NSError *error; LoginModel *userModel = [[LoginModel alloc] initWithString:myJSONString error:&error];`

Comment: @AlejandroIván yes, this is how I am creating my object: NSError *error;
                LoginModel *user = [[LoginModel alloc] initWithDictionary:JSON error:&error];

Comment: And how are you accessing your data? Like this? `float balance = user.user.balance`?

Comment: @AlejandroIván like this userModel.user.firstName

Comment: Your problem seems to be creating the object rather than specifying the structure. Please update your question to show us the relevant code.

Comment: @AlejandroIván shall I show you the response sample?

Comment: You should add everything that's needed to reproduce the problem. Right now, we can't just keep asking you "what happens if...?" because this could be a looong conversation and your problem is probably simple to solve.

Comment: @AlejandroIván I have edited the question. Please have a look.